# git client on solaris 10 and dependencies

Tags: git, centos, dependencies, solaris

I'm having difficulties with git client installation for sun solaris.

I have installed git server on Centos 6. This server will work as a source code repository. Now I want to install git client into my application server - Solaris 10.

Due to company policy, this server is not within internet segment.

As such:

1. How can I find the right download package for solaris 10?
2. This website (http://www.opencsw.org/package/git/) indicates a list of dependencies on solaris 10; `libcurl4`, `libexpat1`, `libiconv2`, `libintl8`, `libssl1_0_0`, `libz1`; will this libraries impact my current source code?

Answer (score 0):

> will this libraries impact my current source code?

They will impact how well git will run as a service able to update your source code (push/pull, commit, ...). Git needs those libraries to be installed in order to run properly.

> due to company policy, this server is not within internet segment.

That means you need to download its package or package source from a machine which has internet access, then upload that same package on the app server.
If only the sources for Git are available, you will need to compile them in order to install Git (as in [this article](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://gorthx.wordpress.com/2009/02/25/git-on-solaris/))

Answer (score 0):

OpenCSW will install stuff to `/opt/csw`, you only have to include `/opr/csw/bin` to your `PATH` env. variable. Dependencies only affect runtime of `git` commands. You don't need to link against this stuff to have `git` commands working.

In fact no issue, your server is not in public net. I have the same policy on servers. I'm forwarding proxy port to servers via `ssh` - running `polipo` on my Linux workstation to be proxy for remote Solaris and reaching those servers via special hop server. Works well even with management tools like Ansible. You have to enable `sshd` port forwarding (off by default) on Solaris side (and disable after install if obliged by policy) and setup `http_proxy=http://localhost:yourport`, then OpenCSW `pkgutil` will work like on direct inet connection.